# How To aciheve sticky header feature like instagram?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in Iphone in which i want to add sticky header feature like instagram.I am searching for this for a while,But everybody is saying about the CSS designs.Can anybody help me how to achieve this in our tableview?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the name bit in Instagram?

If so then it looks like that is just a standard header from a plain style `UITableView`.

What they appear to have done is give every photo a section of the table (instead of a row) and then in each section is a row for the photo, a row for the comments, a row for the likes, etc.

If you use the `UITableViewStylePlain` instead of `UITableViewStyleGrouped` then what it is currently doing is the standard behaviour.

Comment: i am using sections.and grouped tableview.each section for a row.i need that sticky header like feature in instagram

Comment: The fundamental difference between grouped and plain tableviews is that the headers scroll and float (respectively) with the rows. If you want a floating (sticky) header then switch to plain tableview. You may need to change a couple of things once you switch but it will be a damn site less to change than trying to write your own floating header for a grouped tableview. TBH, I wouldn't even know where to start with that.